# MS SQL get field list from an stored procedure without executing

Tags: sql-server

Need to get list of fields produced by a stored procedure. But it needs to not execute the stored procedure at that time.

The stored procedure may be destructive.
The stored procedure may use temporary tables.
The stored procedure may use cursors.

SET FMTONLY ON; doesn't work with temporary tables.

SET NOEXEC  ON; doesn't work as it doesn't return a field list.

I'm limited it what I can do with the stored procedures, but I could request that all temporary tables be enclosed with something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_PSH]
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO #PSH_Temp FROM dbo.SomeTable

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PSH_Temp) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      ~~DO SOME CHANGES~~
      SELECT * FROM #PSH_Temp

      DROP TABLE #PSH_Temp
    END
  ELSE
    SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE 1 = 0
END
```

But even this attempt at working around the SET FMTONLY ON; didn't work.

And it would be best if I could avoid any and all changes to the stored procedures. Not been able to find a workable solution so far.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: do you want the proc not to fire, or just for data not to be returned? These are separate issues. Which field list do you want returned? From what table? From this example, it'd be all the fields in SomeTable...

Comment: What version of SQL are you running?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to do here. I think you want to determine the output of a stored procedure without actually executing it? This is pretty much impossible. There can be multiple result sets and there is also the possibility of dynamic sql which generates a dynamic number of columns. You need to explain what you are trying to accomplish more clearly.

Comment: Based on the title and the first paragraph, I'd guess OP doesn't want the proc to fire at all.

Comment: @scsimon I don't want it to fire the proc. In the example SomeTable is just a place holder, as the data may be retrieved from an existing table, or a temporary table. Or even a SELECT 1 AS FieldName, * FROM SomeTable.

Comment: @GarethLyons MS SQL 2012 upwards (just investigated further and shouldn't actually be using FMTONLY at all, should be using sp_describe_first_result_set, but that has the same issue as FMTONLY)

Comment: @SeanLange One thing that I can assume is that any given SP is only going to return one result set, the program ignores and additional result sets. "I think you want to determine the output of a stored procedure without actually executing it? This is pretty much impossible." sounds about right.

Comment: Yeah as you suspected this is impossible. You would literally have to write your own parser to solve this. I suppose it might be possible but it would take months or even years to get it right and even then it is possible to be slightly different then the MS engine. It is going to be faster and accurate to just do this by analyzing the procedure(s) and document it by hand.

Comment: Thanks all for the attention. I'm going to have to go with it's not possible. Going to trap the error from the FMTONLY, send response to UI, get them to confirm if to exec SP or not, then offer the manual entry solution if the SP must absolutely not be executed. I did try to trick the SP by doing a SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE 1=0 UNION actually query. But it throws up the same error. Still if anyone out there works it out would be much appreciated.